# Seq2Seq use of buckets in TensorFlow tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering why the buckets are being introduced in the Seq2Seq TensorFlow tutorial. I understand the efficiency gain from not processing the padding symbols, but you can avoid processing the paddings if you use `rnn` and specify the `sequence_length` parameter. Or if you use `dynamic_rnn`.

Is it because it helps distributing the training across multiple devices / machines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is that seq2seq was created before dynamic rnn was available. The other is that, even with dynamic rnn, it still helps for speed if your batches are organized by bucket.

Comment: I agree with first reason :) But why would the bucket help ? Even with the bucket size close to the phrase size, there is still some padding processing. Let's say that at runtime you want to do a single phrase processing, to simplify things. The phrase has 7 words, so it would have to be padded to 10 for the first bucket, resulting in 3 pads being processed.My understading is that dynamic rnn would only process the 7, right ?

Comment: I looked through the code and I now understand your point. Buckets won't help for a single execution (the example I gave), but they will for a batch.